# Keeping IDs conditional on repeating variable

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can very efficiently (without much R code) retain only 'ID' cases where instances of 'X' are equal to zero? For example, in this case only ID number 3 should be retained in my data set.

**THIS ISSUE IS CLOSED - THERE ARE MULTIPLE STRONG ANSWERS IN THE COMMENTS BELOW**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), y=c(5,6,4,6,3,1,9,5,5), x=c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0))
subset(df, !ID %in% subset(df, x!=0)$ID)
```

That is, first find the ID's where `x` is not zero (`subset(df, x!=0)$ID`), and then exclude cases with those ID's (`!ID %in% subset(df, x!=0)$ID`)

Comment: This is brilliant - very efficient and gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

using the data.table package, I was able to quickly pull this together

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), y=c(5,6,4,6,3,1,9,5,5), x=c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0))
df <- df[, .(ident = all(x ==0), y, x), by = ID][ident== TRUE] #aggregate, x, y and identifier by each ID
df[, ident := NULL] # get rid of redundant identifier column
```

Comment: This seems to work. I'll only mention that I get a weird warning message with the last line of code:                                                                                         
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`(ident, NULL)) :
  Adding new column 'ident' then assigning NULL (deleting it).

Comment: Try edited, if you need to keep the original, set `df2 <-...` on line 3, and use `df2[, ident := NULL]` in line 4

Answer (score 1):

try this:
first get all IDs for which any row has a non-zero value
Then use that to subset

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), y=c(5,6,4,6,3,1,9,5,5), x=c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0))

exclude <- subset(df, x!=0)$ID
new_df <- subset(df, ! ID %in% exclude)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because this code would retain some rows from IDs 1 and 2.

Comment: I see, I though you just wanted to subset based on 'x'. I will edit the comment

Comment: The issue with your new suggestion is that I don't know how to implement it for a data set where there are thousands of IDs and I don't know which ones have cases have all 0's and which ones have some 1's.

Comment: gotcha, so only keep those for which all x equals 0. Edited again

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `ave`, where we select the `ID` if `all` values (`x`) for the ID are 0.

```
df[ave(df$x == 0, df$ID, FUN = all), ]

#  ID y x
#7  3 9 0
#8  3 5 0
#9  3 5 0
```

---

An equivalent `dplyr` solution would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(all(x == 0)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     ID     y     x
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    3.    9.    0.
#2    3.    5.    0.
#3    3.    5.    0.
```

Comment: Default FUN for `ave` is  `mean`, so you could simplify it to `df[ ave(df$x, df$ID)==0,]` (mean `x` is 0, i.e., all x's are 0)

Comment: @lebatsnok that wouldn't be full proof though. What if `x` value is `c(-2, 2)` for an `ID` so it's mean is 0 and it would get selected falsely.